# Storing users selected filtering options to client VIA sessionStorage - work around

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagination, session-storage

The issue I'm having is a little complicated to explain, but I"ll try my best.

I have a whole bunch of filtering options on my web app once a filtering option is ticked my jquery script submits an AJAX request to the filtering script and then returns back the results. I have a script in place that stores the users selected filters to sessionStorage so I could display the user the appropriate filtered results even if the web page is refreshed.

For example if the users clicks on page 2 of the pagination this will cause a page refresh and then my session then returns back all the filtering options that where ticked then my script sends a request to my filtering script VIA AJAX and sends back the appropriate results in JSON format. This works fine, but my problem is if the user disables storage on their web browser, The web app wont function as expected.

Is there a straight forward work around to do what I just mentioned with out using sessionStorage? I need my app to work as expected if even the user blocks storage, cookies etc.

Comment: You need to find *some* place to store it on the local machine. If SessionStorage doesn't work, you can try `LocalStorage`, IndexedDB, or maybe cookies, if the data isn't too large

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks for your suggestion, but what if the user blocks or has plugin that blocks sessionStorage, LocalStorage, IndexedDB and cookies

Comment: Then you'll have to figure out other ways of storing data on a user's machine, or give up and throw an error.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your advise. I guess that's my best bet. I'm all ears to more suggestions.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Just thought of something. What about storing the data server side to a php session or even creating a footprint of the user and storing the data to memcached if the user blocks all of the previously mentioned storage options? Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Sure. Server-side caching is certainly more reliable than client-side caching.

Comment: Thanks!!! This is going to work out perfect!  I'm not going to have to use up  to much memory either as I'm going to only use server side caching for a fail over, I'm estimating I will have to use the fail over on roughly one percent of my users.